# What is the need of using 'put' method to set the value of a property through powershell

Tags: powershell, put

I tried the following cases :

```
$Localhst = $env:ComputerName;
$comp = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$Localhst+',computer');
$user = $comp.Create('User', 'account24');
$user.SetPassword('Welcome1$');
$user.Description = "Created through powershell script client";
$user.SetInfo();
```

I am getting the following exception :

```
Error Occurred while executing powershell command Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "The account already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007
08B0)"
```

But when I am using put method it is working fine :

```
$Localhst = $env:ComputerName;
$comp = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$Localhst+',computer');
$user = $comp.Create('User', 'account24');
$user.SetPassword('Welcome1$');
$user.put("Description","Created through powershell script client");
$user.SetInfo();
```

What is the difference between using put method to set the value and setting the value directly?

Comment: read here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2008/09/12/adsi-put-and-attributes.aspx

Comment: @CB. Can you provide this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code but receive a different error

```
$Localhst = $env:ComputerName;
$comp = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$Localhst+',computer');
$user = $comp.Create('User', 'account24');
$user.SetPassword('Welcome1$');
$user.Description = "Created through powershell script client";
$user.SetInfo();
```

Produce

```
$user.SetInfo();
Exception lors de la définition de « Description » : « Impossible de définir la propriété Value de l'objet PSMemberInfo de type « System.Management.Automation.PSMethod ». »
Au caractère Ligne:5 : 1
+ $user.Description = "Created through powershell script client";
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Exception lors de l'appel de « SetInfo » avec « 0 » argument(s) : « Accès refusé.
 »
Au caractère Ligne:6 : 1
+ $user.SetInfo();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

The message is in French but it significate unable to define the property like this. But if I run it as administrator it create the user (with no description)

[image]